# "dangling" local blocks in scala

Tags: scala, coding-style

In scala it is possible to define a local block in a function. The local block evaluates to the last statements, for example,

```
val x = {val x =1;x+1}
```

Here `x==2`, the inner `val x` is local to that block.

However those local blocks can cause sneaky bugs when writing anonymous classes. For example (from scala's reference)

```
new Iterator[Int]
{...} // new anonymous class inheriting from Iterator[Int]

new Iterator[Int]

{...} //new Iterator[Int] followed by a "dangling" local block
```

Differntiating between the two cases is frustrating.
Sometimes those two code snippets can compile, for instance if instead of `Iterator[Int]`, `Range(0,1,1)` is used.

I thought about it and couldn't find a case where "dangling" local block (ie, a local block whose value isn't use) is needed (or makes the code more elegant).

Is there a case where we want a local block, without using its value (and without putting it in a different function and calling this function)? I'll be glad for an example.

If not, I think it would be nice to issue a warning (or even forbid altogther) whenever `scalac` encounter "dangling" local block. Am I missing something?

Comment: This looks more to me like something to be brought up on Scala mailing lists than discussed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I considered posting it on Scala mailing list, but as I'm new to scala/Java I thought maybe I'm missing something fundumental in my understanding of local blocks (in scala or in general FP), so I decided to check it out here first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  {
    import my.crazy.implicit.functions._

    // use them...
  }

  // code I know isn't touched by them.
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not write

```
new Iterator[Int] {
  ...
}
```

**Edit**:
This is the style used by Programming in Scala (see [sample chapter pdf](http://www.artima.com/samples/chapter20.pdf))

```
new RationalTrait {
  val numerArg = 1 * x
  val denomArg = 2 * x
}
```

and [Java Coding Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc5.html#381).

> Open brace "{" appears at the end of the same line as the declaration statement

Comment: I dislike this coding style (in Java I put opening braces on new lines) but semicolon inference forces me to use it in Scala.  Down with semicolon inference!