# Can I "pimp my library" with an analogue of TraversableLike.map that has nicely variant types?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit-conversion, variance

Suppose I want to add functionality like `map` to a Scala `List`, something along the lines of `list mapmap f`, which applies the function `f` to each element of `list` twice. (A more serious example might be implementing a parallel or distributed map, but I don't want to get distracted by details in that direction.)

My first approach would be

```
object MapMap {
    implicit def createFancyList[A](list: List[A]) = new Object {
        def mapmap(f: A => A): List[A] = { list map { a: A => f(f(a)) } }
    }
}
```

this now works great

```
scala> import MapMap._
import MapMap._

scala> List(1,2,3) mapmap { _ + 1 }
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

except of course it's only for `List`s, and there's no reason we shouldn't want this to work for anything `Traverseable`, with a `map` function, e.g. `Set`s or `Stream`s. So the second attempt looks like

```
object MapMap2 {
    implicit def createFancyTraversable[A](t: Traversable[A]) = new Object {
        def mapmap(f: A => A): Traversable[A] = { t map { a: A => f(f(a)) } }
    }
}
```

But now, of course, the result can't be assigned to a `List[A]`:

```
scala> import MapMap2._
import MapMap2._

scala> val r: List[Int] = List(1,2,3) mapmap { _ + 1 }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Traversable[Int]
 required: List[Int]
```

Is there some middle ground? Can I write an implicit conversion that adds a method to all subclasses of Traversable, and successfully returns objects with that type?

(I'm guess this involves understanding the dreaded `CanBuildFrom` trait, and maybe even `breakout`!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>You can't do this for all Traversables, as they don't guarantee that map returns anything more specific than Traversable.</strike> *See Update 2 below.*

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.TraversableLike

class TraversableW[CC[X] <: TraversableLike[X, CC[X]], A](value: CC[A]) {
  def mapmap(f: A => A)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, CC[A]]): CC[A] 
      = value.map(f andThen f)
  def mapToString(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], String, CC[String]]): CC[String]
      = value.map(_.toString)
}

object TraversableW {
  implicit def TraversableWTo[CC[X] <: TraversableLike[X, CC[X]], A](t: CC[A]): TraversableW[CC, A] 
      = new TraversableW[CC, A](t)
}

locally {
  import TraversableW._

  List(1).mapmap(1+)
  List(1).mapToString
  // The static type of Seq is preserved, *and* the dynamic type of List is also
  // preserved.
  assert((List(1): Seq[Int]).mapmap(1+) == List(3))
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've added another pimped method, `mapToString`, to demonstrate why `TraversableW` accepts two type parameters, rather than one parameter as in Alexey's solution. The parameter `CC` is a higher kinded type, it represents the container type of the original collection. The second parameter, `A`, represents the element type of the original collection. The method `mapToString` is thus able to return the original container type with a different element type: `CC[String`.

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks to @oxbow_lakes comment, I've rethought this. It is indeed possible to directly pimp `CC[X] <: Traversable[X]`, `TraversableLike` is not strictly needed. Comments inline:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.TraversableLike

class TraversableW[CC[X] <: Traversable[X], A](value: CC[A]) {
  /**
   * A CanBuildFromInstance based purely the target element type `Elem`
   * and the target container type `CC`. This can be converted to a
   * `CanBuildFrom[Source, Elem, CC[Elem]` for any type `Source` by
   * `collection.breakOut`.
   */
  type CanBuildTo[Elem, CC[X]] = CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Elem, CC[Elem]]

  /**
   * `value` is _only_ known to be a `Traversable[A]`. This in turn
   * turn extends `TraversableLike[A, Traversable[A]]`. The signature
   * of `TraversableLike#map` requires an implicit `CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], B, That]`,
   * specifically in the call below `CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], A CC[A]`.
   *
   * Essentially, the specific type of the source collection is not known in the signature
   * of `map`.
   *
   * This cannot be directly found instead we look up a `CanBuildTo[A, CC[A]]` and
   * convert it with `collection.breakOut`
   *
   * In the first example that referenced `TraversableLike[A, CC[A]]`, `map` required a
   * `CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, CC[A]]` which could be found.
   */
  def mapmap(f: A => A)(implicit cbf: CanBuildTo[A, CC]): CC[A]
      = value.map[A, CC[A]](f andThen f)(collection.breakOut)
  def mapToString(implicit cbf: CanBuildTo[String, CC]): CC[String]
      = value.map[String, CC[String]](_.toString)(collection.breakOut)
}

object TraversableW {
  implicit def TraversableWTo[CC[X] <: Traversable[X], A](t: CC[A]): TraversableW[CC, A]
      = new TraversableW[CC, A](t)
}

locally {
  import TraversableW._

  assert((List(1)).mapmap(1+) == List(3))

  // The static type of `Seq` has been preserved, but the dynamic type of `List` was lost.
  // This is a penalty for using `collection.breakOut`. 
  assert((List(1): Seq[Int]).mapmap(1+) == Seq(3))   
}
```

What's the difference? We had to use `collection.breakOut`, because we can't recover the specific collection subtype from a mere `Traversable[A]`.

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(repr)
  b.sizeHint(this) 
  for (x <- this) b += f(x)
  b.result
}
```

The `Builder` `b` is initialized with the original collection, which is the mechanism to preserve the dynamic type through a `map`. However, our `CanBuildFrom` disavowed all knowledge of the *From*, by way of the type argument `Nothing`. All you can do with `Nothing` is ignore it, which is exactly what `breakOut` does:

```
def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]) =
  new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
    def apply(from: From) = b.apply();
    def apply() = b.apply()
  }
```

We can't call `b.apply(from)`, no more than you could call `def foo(a: Nothing) = 0`.

Comment: I took a slightly different approach in Scalaz, which is a bit more powerful: http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/CanBuildAnySelf.scala#L24  http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L28

Comment: I don't have the rights to edit it, retronym, but perhaps the formatted of the code block should be extended to include the imports in your example? Cheers!

Comment: btw: what does "locally" do? Googling "scala locally" doesn't seem to find an explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525446/dangling-local-blocks-in-scala http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3594 http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/19469

Comment: Jason - your first statement is not actually correct: the `map` contract on `Traversable` does not even guarantee that the result type is also `Traversable` - for example `"hello".map(_.toUppercase)` would return a `String`

Comment: @retronym Close, but frustratingly, this still doesn't behave as if we inserted a method to the collections hierarchy - it doesn't work for `Array[_]`, `String`, subtypes of `BitSet`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, when you want to return objects with the same type, you need `TraversableLike` (`IterableLike`, `SeqLike`, etc.) instead of `Traversable`. Here is the most general version I could come up with (the separate `FancyTraversable` class is there to avoid inferring structural types and the reflection hit):

```
class FancyTraversable[A, S <: TraversableLike[A, S]](t: S) {
  def mapmap(f: A => A)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S,A,S]): S = { t map { a: A => f(f(a)) } }
}

implicit def createFancyTraversable[A, S <: TraversableLike[A, S]](t: S): FancyTraversable[A, S] = new FancyTraversable(t)
```

Comment: Do I have to import something? I'm getting an "error: not found: type TraversableLike". (2.8.0RC7)

Comment: "import scala.collection._" and "import scala.collection.generic._" at least makes it compile, but now "List(1,2,3) mapmap { _ + 1 }" just gives me "error: value mapmap is not a member of List[Int]".