# Should I use List[A] or Seq[A] or something else?

Tags: design-patterns, scala

I was writing a class that contained some functional-esque methods. First I wrote them using List as parameters and return types. Then I thought "Hey, you could also use a more generic type!" so I replaced the Lists with Seq, hoping that I could make my stuff faster one day by feeding them something else than lists.

So which general purpose stack-like data-structure shall I write my methods and algorithms for? Is there a general pattern I can stick to? All this is because the methods might need to get optimized in the future in case they will form a bottle-neck.

#### Update

I'll try to be a bit more precise: 
Given you know which operations you are using, like reversing, .tail, direct element access, or for comprehensions. Can I choose a type that will *force* efficiency on those operations?

#### Update 2

I'm quite aware of the performance of concrete data structures for various tasks. What I'm not aware of is which data structure might appear as a sub-class of some super type.

For example shall I use TraversableOnce or IndexedSeq instead of List or Array? Will it buy me anything?

#### Additional Question

What is *your* default List-like data-structure signature? Do you write

```
def a(b: List[A]): List[A]
```

or

```
def a(b: TraversableOnce[A]): TraversableOnce[A]
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: Maybe the problem I'm facing is that I know of maybe 5 implementations of collections and 50 super-types/traits. I know which implementation I have to choose, but not which trait.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, in general, you should use `Seq` for your parameters and design your methods to work efficiently with `List`. This way your methods will work ok with most `Seq` implementations and you will not have to convert your seqs prior to use your methods.

**Edit**

Your question has many questions inside.

1. So which general purpose stack-like data-structure shall I write my methods and algorithms for?

   - I think the answer here is `List`. It's  a stack and it's very fast
2. Can I choose a type that will force efficiency on those operations?

   - In general you'll have to rely on a concerete implementation. The performance characteristics are here http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html
3. For example shall I use TraversableOnce or IndexedSeq instead of List or Array? Will it buy me anything?

   - Some abstractions have performance characteristics defined, some others don't. For example `IndexedSeq` scaladoc says "Indexed sequences support constant-time or near constant-time element access and length computation". If you have an `IndexedSeq` parameter and someone passes an `IndexedSeq` implementation that does not have "near-constant time element access", then that someone is breaking the contract and it's not your problem.
4. What is your default List-like data-structure signature?

   - Seq

Comment: This is basically what I have done in my project. This is the kind of answer I was hoping for, but now I'm thinking that maybe there doesn't exist a good all-round answer.

Comment: One problem is that your question has many questions inside, I have updated my answer to try to address each question more specifically

Answer (score 31):

`List` is the default implementation of `LinearSeq`, which in turn is the default implementation of `Seq`, which in turn is the default implementation of `Iterable`, which in turn is the default implementation of `Traversable`.

See the diagrams [here](http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml) and choose the most general type as per your requirements.

---

[image]

---

[This](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/whatsnew/collections-api/collections.html) document might also help.

Answer (score 5):

For background info on the collection library, have a look at the [Scala 2.8 Collections API](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/whatsnew/collections-api/collections.html) article.

If you have specific operations in mind then look in particular at the [Performance Characteristics section](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/whatsnew/collections-api/collections_40.html).

On the design choice on whether to use a specific type of a more general trait, I would say that it depends on what you do in the implementation. For instance if a method accepts a List, it can count on fast prepend and could use this in its implementation. So accepting a more general trait could have unwanted performance results. Also, you'll have to worry about what type you get back.

```
scala> def a[A](t:TraversableOnce[A]): TraversableOnce[A] = t
a: [A](t: TraversableOnce[A])TraversableOnce[A]

scala> a(List(1,2))
res0: TraversableOnce[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> res0.tail
<console>:8: error: value tail is not a member of TraversableOnce[Int]
       res0.tail
```

If you want to write something general, you will probably want to preserve the types. See [Can I "pimp my library" with an analogue of TraversableLike.map that has nicely variant types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225675/257449) for a taste of the issues you'll encounter and some of the solutions.