# Understanding type conversion/error in Scala in this example

Tags: scala

First, here are 3 snippets of code along with their output on Scala 2.10.2

```
// 1.
def one: Seq[List[String]] =
  Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x"))
println(one)
// => List(List(x), List(x)))

// 2.
def two: List[List[String]] =
  Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x"))
println(two)
// =>
// error: type mismatch;
//  found   : Seq[List[String]]
//  required: List[List[String]]
//   Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x"))
// one error found

// 3.
println(Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x")))
// => List(List(x), List(x))
```

The main code in all the 3 snippets is the same -- `Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x"))`

The first and the third snippet show (print) the type as `List[List[String]]`, but the second snippet, which specifies the return type as `List[List[String]]` fails to compile. The first one's return type is `Seq[List[String]]` but it's printed as a `List[List[String]]`.

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of the second snippet is `List[List[String]]`, but the value has type  `Seq[List[String]]`, this is were exception occurs. List is a [subclass](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) of Seq, it's more concrete type. `println` prints out values you have, but not their types, if you want to see the actual type of an expression, print it in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> Seq(List("x")) ++ List(List("x"))
res5: Seq[List[String]] = List(List(x), List(x))
```

see `res5` type is infered as `Seq[List[String]]`, but the value is `List(List(x), List(x))`. List is a case class with automatically overriden toString method, which, for readability is overriden by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet doesn't compile because `Seq.++` returns a `scala.collection.Seq` (see the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq)), which is not a `scala.collection.immutable.List`:

```
def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Seq[B]
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866639/scala-difference-between-a-seq-and-a-list).