# The difference and conversion between Seq[Int] and List[Int]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-conversion, containers, scala-collections

When I input `Seq(1,2,3)` in REPL, it returns me `List(1,2,3)`

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3)
res8: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Therefore, I thought the `List(1,2,3)` may be of type `List[Int]`. And I tried to specify the type for the variable who are assigned to `Seq(1,2,3)`, but unexpectedly, the REPL complains like this:

```
scala> val a:List[Int]=Seq(1,2,3)
<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Int]
 required: List[Int]
       val a:List[Int]=Seq(1,2,3)
```

Does anyone have ideas about what `Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)` mean? Shouldn't it mean `Seq(1,2,3)` returns a list? What is the difference between `Seq[Int]` and `List[Int]`?
And how to convert between  `Seq` and `List`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866639/scala-difference-between-a-seq-and-a-list

Comment: @StuartLC Yes, but it didn't mention how to convert from `Seq` to `List` or `List` to `Seq`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) is a base trait (interface) for sequences and [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) is a concrete implementation of that interface.

Every instance of `List` is already a `Seq` so there's no need to convert anything. You can use `toSeq` method, but I don't see any reason to do so.
To convert `Seq` to a `List` use `toList` method.

Comment: This is still confusing, i.e. `Seq` can be instantiated (or has a builder), but digging up the implementation differences of a list is not straightforward. And instantiating a `Seq` yields a `List` (in the REPL at least).

Comment: Asking for a `Seq` has the same meaning as asking for "a car". Any car. And the factory gets you a nice Toyota - in our case an instance of `List`. Your request was generic and the response is specific. If you want Toyota ask for it directly - explicitly instatiate a `List`.