# How does the Seq shorthand for Scala actually work?

Tags: scala

In Scala, Seq is a trait which corresponds loosely to a List in Java. 
However, in Scala it is possible to do:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)
```

and get a new List with elements 1,2,3.

But Seq is an abstraction? there is no `new` keyword. So how is this magic working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an object from regular classes in Scala in both ways, with or without the `new` keyword. By omitting it you are calling the apply method on the [companion object](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/companion-object.html) of the class.

Here is an example with a trivial class `Foo`

```
class Foo { }
object Foo {
    def apply() = new Foo
}
```

You can both create a Foo object by:

```
val myFooWNew = new Foo
val myFooWONew = Foo()
```

If you have a case class, when you define the case class, the companion object and its apply method are created implicitly for you.

```
case class Bar { }
```

And you can create the object the same both ways:

```
val myBarWNew = new Bar
val myBarWONew = Bar()
```

This is valid with non-abstract classes. Since `Seq` is, as you said, a trait, it lacks a constructor, so it's implementation is (roughly) always in the companion object.

In reality, the `Seq` construction is a bit more complicated, with `GenSeqFactory` and many other classes from inside.

Also there is a `List` class which is more like a `LinkedList` in Java. There is an awesome answer about `Seq` vs `List` in Scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866639/difference-between-a-seq-and-a-list-in-scala).

Comment: `val myFooWONew = Foo`. No, this assigns the companion object itself to `myFooWONew`. You need `= Foo()`.