# scala, guidelines on return type - when prefer seq, iterable, traversable

Tags: scala

When do you choose to type a given function's return type as `Seq` vs `Iterable` vs `Traversable` (or alternatively even deeper within `Seq`'s hierarchy)?

How do you make that decision? We have a lot of code that returns `Seq`s by default (usually starting from results of a DB query and successive transformations). I tend to want to make the return types `Traversable` by default and `Seq` when specifically expecting a given order. But I don't have a strong justification for doing so.

I am perfectly familiar with the definition of each trait, so please don't answer with defining the terms.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a good question. You have to balance two concerns:

- (1) try to keep your API general, so you can change the implementation later
- (2) give the caller some useful operations to perform on the collection

Where (1) asks you to be as little specific about the type (e.g. `Iterable` over `Seq`), and (2) asks you the opposite.

Even if the return type is just `Iterable`, you can still return let's say a `Vector`, so if the caller wishes to gain extra power, it can just call `.toSeq` or `.toIndexedSeq` on it, and that operation is cheap for a `Vector`.

As a measure of the balance, I would add a third point:

- (3) use a type that kind of reflects how the data is organised. E.g. when you can assume that the data does have a sequence, give `Seq`. If you can assume that no two equal objects can occur, give a `Set`. Etc.

Here are my rules of thumb:

- try to use only a small set of collections: `Set`, `Map`, `Seq`, `IndexedSeq`
- I often violate this previous rule, though, using `List` in favour of `Seq`. It allows the caller to do pattern matching with the cons extractors
- use immutable types only (e.g. `collection.immutable.Set`, `collection.immutable.IndexedSeq`)
- do not use concrete implementations (`Vector`), but the general type (`IndexedSeq`) which gives the same API
- if you are encapsulating a mutable structure, only return `Iterator` instances, the caller can then easily generate a strict structure, e.g. by calling `toList` on it
- if your API is small and clearly tuned towards "big data throughput", use `IndexedSeq`

Of course, this is my personal choice, but I hope it sounds sane.

Comment: There is currently a discussion of `IndexedSeq` versus `Vector`. Technically, `IndexedSeq` does not make guarantees of O(1) for append and prepend, only its default implementation `Vector` does. In Scala 2.9.2, `IndexedSeq` uses the efficient `Vector` methods. In 2.10.0-M6 this was broken, but it seems consensus to fix this, so that `IndexedSeq` would still be as fast. I'm adding this comment just as a small warning sign. Some people will say use `Vector` instead of `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: The rationale for using `List` in favor of `Seq` is out-of-date: "it allows the caller to do pattern matching with the cons extractors." This is irrelevant since analogous extractors were added for `Seq` in Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 9):

- Use `Seq` by default everywhere.
- Use `IndexedSeq` when you need to access by index.
- Use anything else only in special circumstances.

These are the "common-sense" guidelines.  They are simple, practical, and work well in practice while balancing principles and performance.  The principles are:

1. Use a type that reflects how the data is organized (thanks OP and ziggystar).
2. Use interface types in both method arguments and return types.  Both inputs and return types of an API benefit from the flexibility of generality.

`Seq` satisfies both principles.  As described in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/seqs.html:

> A sequence is a kind of iterable that has a [finite] length and whose elements have fixed index positions, starting from 0.

90% of the time, your data is a Seq.

Other notes:

- `List` is an implementation type, so you shouldn't use it in an API.  A `Vector` for instance can't be used as a `List` without going through a conversion.
- `Iterable` doesn't define `length`.  `Iterable` abstracts across finite sequences and potentially infinite streams.  Most of the time one is dealing with finite sequences so you "have a length," and `Seq` reflects that.  Frequently you won't actually make use of length.  But it's needed often enough, and is easy to provide, so use `Seq`.

Drawbacks:

There are some slight downsides to these "common-sense" conventions.

- You can't use List cons pattern matching i.e. `case head :: tail => ...` .  You *can* use `:+` and `+:` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147469/1742799).  Importantly, however, matching on `Nil` still works as described in [Scala: Pattern matching Seq[Nothing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068080/scala-pattern-matching-seqnothing).

Footnotes:

- I'm not discussing `Map` here because the question, sensibly, doesn't ask about it.
- I'm only addressing immutable collections here.
- The guidelines I suggest are consistent with [Should I use List[A] or Seq[A] or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634023/should-i-use-lista-or-seqa-or-something-else)

Answer (score 5):

Make your method's return type as specific as possible. Then if the caller wants to keep it as a `SuperSpecializedHashMap` or type it as a `GenTraversableOnce`, they can. This is why the compiler infers the most specific type by default.

Comment: This is good advice for implemented methods, but I would just add that it's a bit trickier for abstract methods.  Having a very specific return type on an interface might force an implementation to convert its returned object unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't completely understand this answer. Yes the caller can keep the type up to how specialized I defined the method's return type. But no more specialized than that correct?

Comment: The problem is that this also locks you into that choice, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb I follow is, depending on implementation, to make the return types as specific as possible and the types of arguments as general as possible. It's an easy to follow rule and it provides you with consistent guarantees on the type properties with maximum freedom.

Say, if you have a function implementation which just traverses a data structure with methods like `map`, `filter` or `fold` - those that are implemented in the trait `Traversable`, you can expect it to perform equally on any type of input collection - be it a `List`, `Vector`, `HashSet` or even a `HashMap`, so your input argument should be specified as `Traversable[T]`. The choice of output type of the function should only depend on its implementation: in this case it should be `Traversable` too. If however in your function you force this data structure to some more specific type with methods like `toList`, `toSeq` or `toSet`, you should specify the appropriate type. Notice the consistency between the implementation and the return type?

If your function accesses the elements of input by index, the input should be specified as `IndexedSeq`, as it is the most general type that provides you with guarantees on effective implementation of method `apply`.

In case of abstract members the same rule applies with the only difference that you should specify the return types based on how you plan to use them instead of implementation, thus most often they will be more general than in implementation. The categorical choices `Seq`, `Set` or `Map` are the most expected.

Following this rule you protect yourself from very common cases of bottleneck when, for instance, items get appended to `List` or `contains` gets called on a `Seq` instead of a `Set`, yet your program remains a nice degree of freedom and is consistent in sense of choice of types.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note:  With Scala 2.13.x, `Traversable` is out of the picture.  `Iterable` is much more general and it was determined that going forward the duality is not justified.  `Iterable` is now at the top of the collections hierarchy and `Traversable` has been deprecated.