# Scala: Pattern matching Seq[Nothing]

Tags: scala

I am trying to match the case where a `Seq` contains `Nothing`.

```
models.Tasks.myTasks(idUser.toInt) match {
  case tasks => tasks.map {
    task => /* code here */
  }
  case _ => "" //matches Seq(models.Tasks)
}
```

How is `Seq[Nothing]` represented in pattern matching ?

Answer (score 17):

Matching against an empty sequence looks like this:

```
val x: Seq[Nothing] = Vector()

x match { 
  case Seq() => println("empty sequence") 
}
```

EDIT: Note that this is more general than `case Nil` since `Nil` is a subclass only of `List`, not `Seq` in general.  Strangely, the compiler is ok with matching against `Nil` if the type is explicitly annotated as `Seq`, but it will complain if the type is any non-`List` subclass of `Seq`.  Thus you can do this:

```
(Vector(): Seq[Int]) match { case Nil => "match" case _ => "no" }
```

but not this (fails with compile-time error):

```
Vector() match { case Nil => "match" case _ => "no" }
```

Comment: better delete my answer then!

Comment: Have added some repl output to my answer to show this in action.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this answer is getting so many upvotes when it is wrong. Nil works just fine.

Comment: @Russell.  Saying `Seq()` calls `List()` behind the scenes since `Seq` is an interface.  However, `List` is not the only implementation of `Seq`.

Comment: It works absolutely fine for me. I've added some more repl output to my answer.

Comment: I see your example of manually creating a Vector doesn't compile though, interesting.

Comment: So, interestingly, this question explains that `Nil` and `List()` are the *same object*.... but have *different* static types. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5981850/586748.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming I understand what you mean correctly, a sequence that contains nothing is empty, which is `Nil`:

```
case Nil => //do thing for empty seq
```

This works even though you're dealing with `Seq`s, not `Lists`:

```
scala> Seq()
res0: Seq[Nothing] = List()

scala> Seq() == Nil
res1: Boolean = true
```

Some more REPL output to show that this works absolutely fine with other subclasses of `Seq`:

```
scala> Nil
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()

scala> val x: Seq[Int] = Vector()
x: Seq[Int] = Vector()

scala> x == Nil
res4: Boolean = true

scala> x match { case Nil => "it's nil" }
res5: java.lang.String = it's nil

scala> val x: Seq[Int] = Vector(1)
x: Seq[Int] = Vector(1)

scala> x match { case Nil => "it's nil"; case _ => "it's not nil" }
res6: java.lang.String = it's not nil
```

As can be seen from the above output, `Nil` is a type all of it's own. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5981850/586748) has some interesting things to say on the matter.

But @dhg is correct that if you manually create a specific subtype such as vector, the match does not work:

```
scala> val x = Vector()
x: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Nothing] = Vector()

scala> x match { case Nil => "yes"} 
<console>:9: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : object Nil
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Nothing]
              x match { case Nil => "yes"}
```

Having said that, I don't know why you would need to force your objects to be a referred to as a specific concrete subclass very often.

Comment: Saying `Seq()` calls `List()` behind the scenes since `Seq` is an interface. However, `List` is not the only implementation of `Seq`, just the default one.  Try it with *any* other kind of `Seq`, and it will fail.

Comment: @dhg `(Vector(): Seq[Int]) match { case Nil => "match" case _ => "no" }` returns "match"

Comment: @Luigi, but `Vector() match { case Nil => "match" case _ => "no" }` doesn't.  I find the mis-match weird.

Comment: @Russell, As Luigi pointed out, there is apparently a difference between matching something annotated as a `Seq` vs being annotated as a subclass of `Seq`.  While I find it confusing to match a generic `Seq` with `case Nil`, it *does* work, so I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: @dhg as you can see, it works fine for vector, and Nil appears to be, not a subclass of `List`, but a type all of its own.

Comment: I have run into the problem with vectors in the wild recently. A third party library which provided a Seq used a Vector as the underlying implementation. Using Nil as the empty sequence check, as suggested with this answer, led to unexpected results.