# The object-functional impedance mismatch

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

In OOP it is good practice to *talk* to interfaces not to implementations. So, e.g., you write something like this (by `Seq` I mean `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` :)):

```scala
// talk to the interface - good OOP practice
doSomething[A](xs: Seq[A]) = ???
```

not something like the following:

```scala
// talk to the implementation - bad OOP practice
doSomething[A](xs: List[A]) = ???
```

However, in pure functional programming languages, such as Haskell, you don't have subtype polymorphism and use, instead, ad hoc polymorphism through type classes. So, for example, you have the list data type and a monadic instance for list. You don't need to worry about using an interface/abstract class because you don't have such a concept.

In hybrid languages, such as Scala, you have both type classes (through a pattern, actually, and not first-class citizens as in Haskell, but I digress) and subtype polymorphism. In `scalaz`, `cats` and so on you have monadic instances for concrete types, not for the abstract ones, of course.

Finally the question: given this *hybridism* of Scala do you still respect the OOP rule to talk to interfaces or just talk to concrete types to take advantage of functors, monads and so on directly without having to convert to a concrete type whenever you need to use them? Put differently, is in Scala still good practice to talk to interfaces even if you want to embrace FP instead of OOP? If not, what if you chose to use `List` and, later on, you realized that a `Vector` would have been a better choice?

P.S.: In my examples I used a simple method, but the same reasoning applies to user defined types. E.g.:

```scala
case class Foo(bars: Seq[Bar], ...)
```

Comment: There's also.. `def doSomething[A, M[X] <: Seq[X]](xs: M[A]) = ???`

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). The main reasons for talking to interfaces is 1) you might want to replace an implementation with another and 2) so you can isolate your types from one another when writing unit tests. These issues do not apply to "primitive" types, like ints, or string - there's no interface for `int` or `string`.

Comment: I consider most monads to be primitives that help you glue your code together. Therefore, there's no need for interfaces.

Comment: I don't think the two collide. There are situations when one can take advantage of the monadic nature of `List`, and times when an abstraction through a `trait` is more important. Also, the concept of a monad by itself is pretty abstract, any method having `pure` and `flatMap` adhere to it, making it pretty easy to chain operations together without knowing the actual "underlying type".

Comment: @dcastro I know what the main reasons to talk to an interface are in OOP and I agree with them. Here, the problem is working with a hybrid language, such as Scala, where you have OOP and FP merged together. I strongly doubt FP experts agree with your view of monads (or functors, for example) being primitives used to glue code together, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov maybe you meant "any type having `pure` and `flatMap` adhere to it". Anyway, this is not enough to be a monad. Monadic laws must be respected.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Which guarantee does the Scala API give you?

Comment: @lambdista My statement may have been too broad. I was referring to stuff like `Option`, `IO` and `State`. To me, they're "primtivies" in the sense that I can't fathom replacing them with some other implementation of `Option`, `IO` and `State`. They're just what they are.

Comment: @dcastro OK. But, strictly speaking, `Option`, `IO`, and so on are not monads. Indeed, they are \* -> \*, while a monad is (\* -> \*) -> \*. So, you can have monad instances for `Option` and so on but they alone are not monads.

Comment: `"avoid both Seq and Iterable because you must assume they are mutable and infinite … not a whole lot you can do safely."` - https://twitter.com/tpolecat/status/618820605069037568

Comment: @KevinMeredith no, you must not. That's why I wrote: "by `Seq` I mean `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`"

Comment: Answers will be opinion based. My answers to your two questions are "yes" and "yes". And in consequence, see also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702798/scala-guidelines-on-return-type-when-prefer-seq-iterable-traversable

Comment: Thank you for your comment @0__

Answer (score 1):

What I would attack here is your "concrete vs. interface" concept.  Look at it this way: every type has an interface, in the general sense of the term "interface."  A "concrete" type is just a limiting case.

So let's look at Haskell lists from this angle.  What's the interface of a list?  Well, lists are an *algebraic data type*, and all such data types have the same general form of interface and contract:

1. You can **construct** instances of the type using its constructors according to their arities and argument types;
2. You can **observe** instances of the type by matching against their constructors according to their arities and argument types;
3. Construction and observation are inverses—when you pattern match against a value, what you get out is exactly what was put into it.

If you look at it in these terms, I think the following rule works pretty well in either paradigm:

- Choose types whose interfaces and contracts match **exactly** with your requirements.

  - If their contract is weaker than your requirements, then they won't maintain invariants that you need;
  - If their contracts are stronger than your requirements, you may unintentionally couple yourself to the "extra" details and limit your ability to change the program later on.

So you no longer ask whether a type is "concrete" or "abstract"—just whether it fits your requirements.

Comment: It's not this way that works in OOP. In Haskell you have data types (ADTs). You have both lists (linked lists) and vectors (int-indexed arrays) but they don't share a common _supertype_. If your function takes a list you cannot pass it a vector. In Java/Scala you have subtype polymorphism and you don't need to care if the client code passes a list or a vector, you just take a Seq (List in Java) and you're done. Plus, in OOP it's good practice taking Seq, not List or Vector, since Seq match exactly your requirement so you don't need to care about the concrete implementation passed in.

Comment: I would argue that the equivalent of oop interfaces in this case is to be considered the haskell typeclass. The abstraction under examination is about writing generic code that works using the minimal needed contract for your data.

Comment: @lambdista: There are simple functions that convert between lists and vectors. Since Haskell lists are lazy, operationally this is very much like iterators/`Seq`.  So there, problem solved. OOP frets too much about IS-A relationships when CAN-BE-TURNED-INTO-A works very well already.

Answer (score 0):

These are my two cents on this subject. In Haskell you have data types (ADTs). You have both lists (linked lists) and vectors (int-indexed arrays) but they don't share a common supertype. If your function takes a list you cannot pass it a vector.

In Scala, being it a hybrid OOP-FP language, you have subtype polymorphism too so you may not care if the client code passes a `List` or a `Vector`, just require a `Seq` (possibly immutable) and you're done.

I guess to answer to this question you have to ask yourself another question: "Do I want to embrace FP *in toto*?". If the answer is yes then you shouldn't use `Seq` or any other abstract superclass in the OOP sense. Of course, the exception to this rule is the use of a trait/abstract class when defining ADTs in Scala. For example:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

In this case one would require `Tree[A]` as a type, of course, and then use, e.g., pattern matching to determine if it's either `Empty` or `Node[A]`.

I guess my feeling about this subject is confirmed by the *red book* ([Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)). There they never use `Seq`, but `List`, `Vector` and so on. Also, haskellers, don't care about these problems and use lists whenever they need linked-list semantic and vectors whenever they need int-indexed-array semantic.

If, on the other hand, you want to embrace OOP and use Scala as a *better Java* then OK, you should follow the OOP best practice to *talk* to interfaces not to implementations.

If you're thinking: "I'd rather opt for *mostly functional*" then you should read Erik Meijer's [The Curse of the Excluded Middle](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2611829).