# How to write a zipWith method that returns the same type of collection as those passed to it?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I have reached this far:

```
implicit def collectionExtras[A](xs: Iterable[A]) = new {
  def zipWith[B, C, That](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Iterable[A], C, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(xs.repr)
    val (i, j) = (xs.iterator, ys.iterator)
    while(i.hasNext && j.hasNext) {
      builder += f(i.next, j.next)
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
// collectionExtras: [A](xs: Iterable[A])java.lang.Object{def zipWith[B,C,That](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Iterable[A],C,That]): That}

Vector(2, 2, 2).zipWith(Vector(4, 4, 4))(_ * _)
// res3: Iterable[Int] = Vector(8, 8, 8)
```

Now the problem is that above method always returns an `Iterable`. How do I make it return the collection of type as those passed to it? (in this case, `Vector`) Thanks.

Comment: `new { def foo = }` produces a value of a structural type, which is invoked through reflection; to avoid this, declare the signatures in a trait ZipWith, and return an instance of this trait. This applies to the question and to all solutions.

Answer (score 9):

You got close enough. Just a minor change in two lines:

```
implicit def collectionExtras[A, CC[A] <: IterableLike[A, CC[A]]](xs: CC[A]) = new {
  def zipWith[B, C, That](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], C, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(xs.repr)
    val (i, j) = (xs.iterator, ys.iterator)
    while(i.hasNext && j.hasNext) {
      builder += f(i.next, j.next)
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
```

First, you need to get the collection type being passed, so I added `CC[A]` as a type parameter. Also, that collection needs to be able to "reproduce" itself -- that is guaranteed by the second type parameter of `IterableLike` -- so `CC[A] <: IterableLike[A, CC[A]]`. Note that this second parameter of `IterableLike` is `Repr`, precisely the type of `xs.repr`.

Naturally, `CanBuildFrom` needs to receive `CC[A]` instead of `Iterable[A]`. And that's all there is to it.

And the result:

```
scala> Vector(2, 2, 2).zipWith(Vector(4, 4, 4))(_ * _)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(8, 8, 8)
```

Comment: dropping down to `hasNext` and all that means it doesn't work on infinite Streams. huynhjl's solution does.

Comment: I have two issues with your answer: a) you write `CC[A]`, which is problematic when zipping lists (there's a reason why the Scala collections library does not use higher-ranked types this way, and I'm sure you know).
b) Also this answer makes `collectionExtras` return type be a structural type (and thus inefficient).

Comment: @Blaisorblade if you look at my comment to axel22, at the time the other solution did not occur to me. As for structural type, I don't see how it comes to be -- structural types can be tricky that way. :-/

Comment: About structural types, I don't see what's tricky, so I guess I don't understand you. The return type is `java.lang.Object{def zipWith...`, i.e. a structural type, and that's of course the case since you use `new {def ...` and the defined method (`zipWith`) is not a method of `Object`.
The complete type is:
`collectionExtras: [A, CC[A] <: scala.collection.IterableLike[A,CC[A]]](xs: CC[A])java.lang.Object{def zipWith[B,C,That](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[CC[A],C,That]): That}`

Comment: @Blaisorblade Oh, duh! It's been a long time, and I didn't even realize the answer starts with `new {`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem above is that your implicit conversion `collectionExtras` causes the obtained object to lose type information. In particular, in the solution above, the concrete collection type is lost because you're passing it an object of type `Iterable[A]` - from this point on, the compiler no longer knows the real type of `xs`. Although the builder factory `CanBuildFrom` programatically ensures that the dynamic type of the collection is correct (you really get a `Vector`), statically, the compiler knows only that `zipWith` returns something that is an `Iterable`.

To solve this problem, instead of having the implicit conversion take an `Iterable[A]`, let it take an `IterableLike[A, Repr]`. Why?

`Iterable[A]` is usually declared as something like:

```
Iterable[A] extends IterableLike[A, Iterable[A]]
```

The difference with `Iterable` is that this `IterableLike[A, Repr]` keeps the concrete collection type as `Repr`. Most concrete collections, in addition to mixing in `Iterable[A]`, also mix in the trait `IterableLike[A, Repr]`, replacing the `Repr` with their concrete type, like below:

```
Vector[A] extends Iterable[A] with IterableLike[A, Vector[A]]
```

They can do this because type parameter `Repr` is declared as covariant.

Long story short, using `IterableLike` causes you implicit conversion to keep the concrete collection type information (that is `Repr`) around and use it when you define `zipWith` - note that the builder factory `CanBuildFrom` will now contain `Repr` instead of `Iterable[A]` for the first type parameter, causing the appropriate implicit object to be resolved:

```
import collection._
import collection.generic._

implicit def collectionExtras[A, Repr](xs: IterableLike[A, Repr]) = new {
  def zipWith[B, C, That](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, C, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(xs.repr)
    val (i, j) = (xs.iterator, ys.iterator)
    while(i.hasNext && j.hasNext) {
      builder += f(i.next, j.next)
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
```

Reading your question formulation more carefully ("How to write a zipWith method that returns the same type of collection as those passed to it?"), it seems to me that you want to have the same type of collection as those passed to `zipWith`, not to the implicit conversion, that is the same type as`ys`.

Same reasons as before, see solution below:

```
import collection._
import collection.generic._

implicit def collectionExtras[A](xs: Iterable[A]) = new {
  def zipWith[B, C, That, Repr](ys: IterableLike[B, Repr])(f: (A, B) => C)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, C, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(ys.repr)
    val (i, j) = (xs.iterator, ys.iterator)
    while(i.hasNext && j.hasNext) {
      builder += f(i.next, j.next)
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
```

With results:

```
scala> immutable.Vector(2, 2, 2).zipWith(mutable.ArrayBuffer(4, 4, 4))(_ * _)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(8, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Interesting. It never occurred to me to get an `IterableLike[_, Repr]`, and parameterize on `Repr`.

Comment: I guess one advantage could be in case `Repr` is a `String`, or some other unparametrized type, as in `StringOps`.

Comment: dropping down to `hasNext` and all that means it doesn't work on infinite Streams. huynhjl's solution does.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest I'm not sure how that really works:

```
implicit def collectionExtras[CC[X] <: Iterable[X], A](xs: CC[A]) = new {
  import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def zipWith[B, C](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)
  (implicit cbf:CanBuildFrom[Nothing, C, CC[C]]): CC[C] = {
    xs.zip(ys).map(f.tupled)(collection.breakOut)
  }
}

scala> Vector(2, 2, 2).zipWith(Vector(4, 4, 4))(_ * _)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(8, 8, 8)
```

I sort of monkey patched [this answer from retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225675/can-i-pimp-my-library-with-an-analogue-of-traversablelike-map-that-has-nicely-v/3226114#3226114) until it worked!

Basically, I want to use the `CC[X]` type constructor to indicate that `zipWith` should return the collection type of `xs` but with `C` as the type parameter (`CC[C]`). And I want to use `breakOut` to get the right result type. I sort of hoped that there was a `CanBuildFrom` implicit in scope but then got this error message:

```
required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Iterable[(A, B)],C,CC[C]]
```

The trick was then to use `Nothing` instead of `Iterable[(A, B)]`. I guess that implicit is defined somewhere...

Also, I like to think of your `zipWith` as `zip` and then `map`, so I changed the implementation. Here is with your implementation:

```
implicit def collectionExtras[CC[X] <: Iterable[X], A](xs: CC[A]) = new {
  import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def zipWith[B, C](ys: Iterable[B])(f: (A, B) => C)
  (implicit cbf:CanBuildFrom[Nothing, C, CC[C]]) : CC[C] = {
    val builder = cbf()
    val (i, j) = (xs.iterator, ys.iterator)
    while(i.hasNext && j.hasNext) {
      builder += f(i.next, j.next)
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
```

Note [this article](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7846) provides some background on the type constructor pattern.

Comment: if you use zip and map instead of dropping down to the Iterator level, then it works with infinite Streams. +1!