# Adding Haskell's Monadic Bind Operator to Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, implicit-conversion

In Haskell, you can use the bind operator (`>>=`) like this:

```
repli :: [a] -> [a]
repli xs = xs >>= \x -> [x,x]

*Main> repli [1,2,3]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

I've read that `flatMap` is Scala's bind operator:

```
def repli [A](xs: List[A]): List[A] =
  xs.flatMap { x => List(x,x) }

scala> repli (List(1,2,3))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

As a pedagogic exercise, I'm trying to add support for `>>=` to Scala:

```
class MyList[T](list: List[T]) {
  def >>= [U](f: T => List[U]): List[U] = list.flatMap(f)
}
implicit def list2mylist[T](list: List[T]) = new MyList(list)

def repliNew [A](xs: List[A]): List[A] =
  xs >>= { x: A => List(x,x) }

scala> repliNew (List(1,2,3))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

This works perfectly, but only for Lists.  I really want to support any class with a `flatMap` method.  Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: (Anything relevant in [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)?)

Comment: If you are okay with only the members of the collections hierarchy--e.g. not `Option` without extra work--then you can use the method shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word:  pedagogic

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) does it as follows:

```
trait MA[M[_], A] {
  def value: M[A]
  def >>=(f: A => M[B])(implicit m: Monad[M]): M[B] =
    m.bind(value, f)
}
```

With implicit conversions from `M[A]` to `MA[M, A]` for all `M[_]` and `A`:

```
implicit def ma[M[_], A](m: => M[A]): MA[M, A] = new MA[M, A] {
  lazy val value = m
}
```

You just need a trait `Monad` and an instance of it for every monad you care about:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: => A): M[A]
  def bind[A, B](m: M[A], f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What about adding a synonym for `flatMap` with an implicit class?

```
implicit class BindRich[A,B](fm:{def flatMap(a:A):B}) {
  def >>=(a:A):B = fm.flatMap(a)
}
```

With this in scope any object having the method `flatMap` will also have `>>=`.

Comment: Note that this may use reflection under the hood.