# Implementing recurrence relations on State monads (in Haskell or Scala)

Tags: haskell, monads, moving-average, state-monad, recurrence

I am working on a new implementation of the operators in http://www.thalesians.com/archive/public/academic/finance/papers/Zumbach_2000.pdf 
EDIT: clearer explanation here: https://www.olseninvest.com/customer/pdf/paper/001207-emaOfEma.pdf

Briefly, it's a whole bunch of cool time series operators based on the recurrence relation of the exponential moving average, where each application of the ema() operator takes the new value and the previous result of the ema.  I can't seem to do latex on this stack exchange, but anyway my problem now is a software problem.

I implemented this in Scala by hiding a var deep inside the thunks that create EMA functions.  This all works, but it's super tricky, because calling ema(5) and then ema(5) again will naturally lead to a different result.  I'd like to try redoing all of this using State Monads, but I'm quickly getting lost in the weeds.

For example, I have the following simplified EMA State monad in Haskell:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type EMAState = Double
type Tau = Double

ema :: Tau -> Double -> State EMAState Double
ema tau x = state $ \y ->
  let alpha = 1 / tau
      mu = exp(-alpha)
      mu' = 1 - mu
      y' = (mu * y) + (mu' * x)
  in (y', y')
```

which I can readily test in GHCI:

```
*Main Control.Monad.State> runState (ema 5 10) 0
(1.8126924692201818,1.8126924692201818)
```

applying the input 10 to a 5-period EMA initialized to 0.  This is all well and good, using forM I can apply multiple input values etc.  Now, the next step is to implement an "iterated EMA", which is an EMA applied to itself N times.

```
iEMA[n](x) = EMA(iEMA[n-1](x))
```

Each of these intermediate EMAs will need to have their own state, aka previous result, to correctly calculate the vector of iterated EMAs.  So, what I am looking for, is something which like this, (I think):

```
iema :: Int -> Tau -> Double -> State [EMAState] [Double]
```

Which is essentially a daisy chain of EMAs:

```
iEMA[3](x) = EMA(EMA(EMA(x,s1),s2),s3) = (x, [s1,s2,s3]) -> ([y1,y2,y3], [s1',s2',s3'])
```

And if all I care about is the 3rd iterated EMA ...

```
... -> (y3, [s1', s2', s3'])
```

The paper moves on from there, creating ever more complex operators built on iterated EMAs and averages of them etc, so I want to be able to functionally and purely compose these stateful operators building ever more complex states, but still quite simple input and output.

I really feel like this is what functional programming is good at, but I don't yet have the expertise to see how to put together these State monads in the correct way.  Could someone please point me in the right direction with these iterated recurrence operators?

EDIT:

A couple of helpful folks have suggested repeated application of the same ema operator to the input data, but this is not sufficient.  Each ema operator needs to maintain it's own previous value.  Here's an example:

```
tau 5               
mu  0.818730753             
muprime 0.181269247             
        ema1    ema2    ema3     
    x   0       0       0       <- States_0
    1   0.1812  0.03285 0.00595 <- States_1
    5   1.0547  0.21809 0.04441 <- States_2
```

The x column is the raw input, ema1 uses its left for input and it's up for recurrence/state.  ema2 uses its left for input (not x!) and it's up for state.  It's an ema (ema (x) ).  Ditto ema3 = ema (ema (ema (x) ) ).  What I would like to do, which I think must be possible, is given an ema state monad, compose the ema3 state monad, or even better, the [ema] state monad with each each subsequent ema operating on the output of the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer...

Define:

```
combine :: [ a -> State s a ] -> a -> State [s] a
combine fs a = state $ \ys ->
  let zs = zipWith (\f y a -> runState (f a) y) fs ys
      pairs = chain a zs
      as' = map fst pairs
      a' = last as'         -- we are only returning one result in this case
      ys' = map snd pairs
  in (a', ys')

chain :: a -> [ a -> (a,s) ] -> [ (a,s) ]
chain a [] = []
chain a (f:fs) = let (a',s) = f a
                 in (a',s) : chain a' fs

ema3 t = combine $ replicate 3 (ema t)

ghci> runState (ema3 5 1) [0,0,0]
(5.956242778945897e-3,[0.18126924692201818,3.2858539879675595e-2,5.956242778945897e-3])

ghci> runState (do ema3 5 1; ema3 5 5) [0,0,0]
(4.441089130249448e-2,[1.0547569416524334,0.21809729359983737,4.441089130249448e-2])
```

The `combine` is easily modified to return all of the results - just return `as'` instead of `a'`.

Original answer:

```
 combine :: (a -> State s b) -> (b -> State t c) -> (a -> State (s,t) c)
 combine f g a = state $ \(s,t) ->
   let (b,s') = runState (f a) s
       (c,t') = runState (g b) t
   in (c,(s',t'))
```

Then:

```
ema3 tau = ema tau `combine` ema tau `combine` ema tau
```

and `em3` has type:

```
ema3 :: Tau -> Double -> State ((EMAState, EMAState), EMAState) Double
```

For instance:

```
ghci> runState (ema3 5 1) ((0,0),0)
(5.956242778945897e-3,((0.18126924692201818,3.2858539879675595e-2),5.956242778945897e-3))
```

Note that the state type of `ema3` is `((Double,Double),Double)` and not a 3-tuple or list.

In your example you run `(ema3 5)` first with input `x = 1` and then with input `x = 5`
with initial state `((0,0),0)`:

```
ghci> runState (do ema3 5 1; ema3 5 5) ((0,0),0)
(4.441089130249448e-2,((1.0547569416524334,0.21809729359983737),4.441089130249448e-2))
```

and that gives you the second row in the table.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to chew on.  I will probably attempt to make a version [(a -> State s a)] -> (a -> State [s] [a]), which could be combined with a repeat to get Integer -> (a -> State s a) -> (a -> State [s] [a]) I think...

Comment: Rather than modify combine to return all or one result, I (finally!) came up with:
`lastM :: State s [a] -> State s a
lastM s = do
  xs <- s
  return $ last xs`

And then `iema n t = lastM . iemas n t`  where `iemas n t = combine $ replicate n (ema t)` as you pointed out.  I still feel like I am not quite 'getting it' but this has helped, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's build the handy old Mealy machine

```
data Mealy i o where
  Mealy :: (i -> s -> (i, s)) -> s -> Mealy i o
```

which has all kinds of instances

```
instance Arrow Mealy
instance ArrowChoice Mealy
instance ArrowApply Mealy
instance Strong Mealy
instance Choice Mealy
instance Profunctor Mealy
instance Category * Mealy
instance Monad (Mealy a)
instance Functor (Mealy a)
instance Applicative (Mealy a)
instance Pointed (Mealy a)
```

We can use it to build recurrence relations

```
recur :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Mealy a a
recur f a0 = Mealy (\inp prior -> let post = f inp prior in (post, post)) a0
```

we can iterate them with our `Category` instance

```
iter :: Int -> Mealy a a -> Mealy a a
iter 0 _ = id
iter 1 m = m
iter n m = m >>> iter (n-1) m
```

and then, with all this machinery, we can create an infinite stream of iterated Mealy machines

```
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a) deriving Functor

instance Functor Stream
instance Applicative Stream
instance Foldable Stream
instance Traversable Stream

ints :: Stream Int
ints = go 0 where go n = Stream n (go $ n + 1)

jet :: Mealy a a -> Stream (Mealy a a)
jet m = fmap (`iter` m) ints
```

All of these together give us, essentially, your desired structure. But it's a little difficult to interact with directly. We'll give it its own instances to help

```
newtype MealyJet i o = MealyJet { runMealyJet :: Stream (Mealy i o) }

instance Profunctor MealyJet
instance Applicative (MealyJet i)

instance Category MealyJet where
  id = MealyJet (pure id) -- technically this should be `jet id`, but it's equal to pure
  MealyJet f . MealyJet g = MealyJet (liftA2 (.) f g)

viewMealyJet :: MealyJet i o -> Mealy i (Stream o)
viewMealyJet (MealyJet m) = sequenceA m
```

And now, we can write these EMAs as needed

```
type Tau = Double

ema :: Tau -> Mealy Double Double
ema tau = recur $ \fresh prior -> 
  let alpha = 1 / tau
      mu    = exp (negate alpha)
      mu'   = 1 - mu
   in (mu * y) + (mu' * x)

emaJet :: Tau -> MealyJet Double Double
emaJet = MealyJet . jet . ema

emaComp :: MealyJet Double Double
emaComp = emaJet 1 >>> emaJet 2 >>> emaJet 3 >>> emaJet 4 >>> emaJet 5

fiveStack :: Mealy Double (Stream Double)
fiveStack = viewMealyJet emaComp
```

Comment: This looks excellent too, I will need to read up on these Mealy /Mooremachines.  Thanks!

Comment: Mealy is probably what you want—Moore was my initial stab but I had gotten them confused.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be fully understanding your use case, but possibly you are looking for something like this:

```
ema' _ [] = get >>= return
ema' tau (x:xs) = do
  y <- get
  let alpha = 1 / tau
      mu = exp $ negate alpha
      mu' = 1 - mu
      y' = (mu * y) + (mu' * x)
  put y'
  ema' tau xs
```

It is like your original function except it accepts a list of `x` values, and it recursively executes for each one, updating `y` each time. When none are left, it returns the value of `y` as the answer.

It can be run like so:

```
*Main> evalState (ema' 5 [10]) 0
1.8126924692201818
*Main> evalState (ema' 5 [10, 10]) 0
3.2967995396436076
*Main> evalState (ema' 5 [10, 10, 10]) 0
4.511883639059737
```

When using the `State` monad, you don't need to wrap your functions in the `state $ \y -> ...` business. You can simply enclose your monadic code in a `do` block and use `put` and `get` to access the state. In this case, for each recursive execution of the function, I grab the last `y` with `get`, and then use `put` after doing math to update the state.

I think that in your version, you are including the `State` monad without actually getting anything for it (since you don't use `put` or `get`).

Also, the `State` monad may be overkill for this; you could accomplish the same thing using a fold over a list of x values.

Comment: This isn't quite the problem I am having - above is I believe a solution for applying a stateful ema operator to a sequence of values. I am trying to figure out how to compose a sequence of stateful/recurrence ema operators into a single stateful operator which takes a single value, calculates the ema of it +state, then uses that as input to another party ema operator, which uses that value plus IT'S  state, etc etc.

Comment: I do think the state monad is an approach, but I am stuck on how to compose N state monad computations end-to-end like a pipeline, with each stage having its state and updating it's state, and the entire pipeline then having a compound state.

Comment: Note that I think this would all be quite easy using Rx Observables with scan() or something similar in Scalaz.Stream or something equivalent in haskell, but I would like to have the state explicit first, then hopefully wrap it up into a stream afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

Update based on the comments...

Three iterations of `ema` can be written using the monadic bind operator `>>=` like this:

```
ema3 tau x = ema tau x >>= ema tau >>= ema tau
```

or using the Kleisli arrow:

```
ema3 tau = ema tau >=> ema tau >=> ema tau
```

As a diagram the computation flows like this:

```
          y1          /---------\
           |          |         |
           v          |         v
  x  -->  EMA   -->  EMA  -->  EMA  -->  x' = y3'
          tau        tau       tau 
           |          ^         |
           |          |         v
           \----------/         y3'
```

(Original answer)

This is not a complete answer, but perhaps the OP comment
on whether this is going in the right direction.

Here is what I understand the computation looks like:

```
          y1         y2        y3
           |          |         |
           v          v         v
  x  -->  EMA   -->  EMA  -->  EMA  -->  x'
          tau1       tau2      tau3
           |          |         |
           v          v         v
          y1'        y2'       y3'
```

The question is whether there is an elegant way to
express this as a composition of EMA blocks, e.g.
something like:

```
ema tau1 >o> ema tau2 >o> ema tau3
```

for some operator `>o>`.

Comment: Yes, except the taus can be all the same, and x'==y3' (just as the input the the second ema is y1').

Comment: I definitely am looking for something like that operator. In my Scala implementation after lifting the recurrence operator into the sneaky stateful Double - > Double, I compose them using normal function composition. So I think I am looking for a . or pipeline operator that understands state monads where the states are the previous values of a recurrence operator.

Comment: see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5436383/866915) for a scala version of the monadic bind operator, and web searches suggest that `scalaz` implements the Kleisii arrow.

Comment: in your question, the reference to `[s1,s2,s3]` as state was confusing. If my updated answer is correct the state consists of only one number, and you are just iterating the `ema tau` effect three times. You don't get `...  -> (y3, [s1', s2', s3'])` so I want to make sure my interpretation is correct.

Comment: I don't believe this is what I want, there is definitely more than one state number.  Let my update my question.

Comment: so my original grid diagram is what you want

Comment: Yes, that's much more like I imagine - given the basic ema(tau)(x,s) -> y operator, build an iema(tau)(x,[s]) -> [y] operator.  edit: the part I haven't figured out is how to build aggregate state monads from smaller state monads, but I am still reading up on monad transformers etc.