# Operating on Scala collections in generic way

Tags: generics, scala, types, scala-collections, generic-programming

I wrote the function to find [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (LCS). For example, for two sequences of chars BANANA and ATANA it returns AANA. Implementation is naive inefficient adaptation of recursive algorithm, but it is irrelevant for purpose of this question.

```
def LCS[T](a: Seq[T], b: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
    if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty)
      Seq.empty
    else if (a.head == b.head)
      a.head +: LCS(a.tail, b.tail)
    else {
      val case1 = LCS(a.tail, b)
      val case2 = LCS(a, b.tail)
      if (case1.length > case2.length) case1 else case2
    }
}
```

I want to refactor this function in **most generic way** possible. Current implementation works for any types of input sequences, but always returns collection of type List[T]. I want to achieve following behaviour:

```
LCS(List('B','A','N','A','N','A'), List('A','T','A','N','A')) -> List('A','A','N','A')
LCS(Vector('B','A','N','A','N','A'), Vector('A','T','A','N','A')) -> Vector('A','A','N','A')

...and so on for all other Seqs...
```

It would be wonderful if LCS could also handle *String*s and *Array*s:

```
LCS("BANANA", "ATANA") -> "AANA"
LCS(Array('B','A','N','A','N','A'), Array('A','T','A','N','A')) -> Array('A','A','N','A')
```

I believe with help of Scala 2.8 generic collection library it's possible to achieve at least first requirement. Will be glad to see "heavy" machinery like higher-kinded polymorphism, type classes, CanBuildFrom and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Although this is not *exactly* on target, you should be able to accomplish what you want by following the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846 .  I recommend that you not use straightforward recursion, however, since you will have to make a ridiculous number of builders to do it that way. A helper function that recursed with builders would do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To flush out my comment, here is what you'd do (no explanation given--for that, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846)).

```
def LCS[A,C](a: C, b: C)(
  implicit c2i: C => Iterable[A], cbf: collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[C,A,C]
): C = {
  val builder = cbf()
  def ListLCS(a: Iterable[A], b: Iterable[A]): List[A] = {
    if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) Nil
    else if (a.head==b.head) a.head :: ListLCS(a.tail,b)
    else {
      val case1 = ListLCS(a.tail, b)
      val case2 = ListLCS(a, b.tail)
      if (case1.length > case2.length) case1 else case2
    }
  }
  builder ++= ListLCS( c2i(a), c2i(b) )
  builder.result()
}
```

It is possible to use a builder directly inside the inner function, but you'd have to rework the algorithm; as it is, you add items to the head of the list, whereas builders add to the end.  So, in order to keep the same algorithm, we make a list as an intermediate.

Comment: Thanks Rex! Your wonderful [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846) of "pimping" scala collections is exactly what I wanted to know. MUST READ to everyone interested in integrating own generic methods operating on collections with scala collection framework.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `Seq.empty` with `a.companion.empty` gave me a function with this behavior:

```
scala> LCS(Vector(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), Vector(1, 1, 3))
res3: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 1, 3)

scala> LCS(List(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), List(1, 1, 3))
res4: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1, 3)

scala> LCS("BANANA", "ANA")                       
res5: Seq[Char] = Vector(A, N, A)

scala> LCS(Array(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), Array(1, 1, 3))
res6: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 3)
```

Comment: It's only partial solution. As you can see, compile-time type in every case is Seq[T]. Besides it doesn't work with Strings and Arrays in proper way. See Rex Kerr's answer above, he solved problem completely.