# Enriching Scala collections with a method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-collections, enrich-my-library

How do I add a `foreachWithIndex` method on Scala collections?

This is what I could come up with so far:

```
implicit def iforeach[A, CC <: TraversableLike[A, CC]](coll: CC) = new {
  def foreachWithIndex[B](f: (A, Int) => B): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    for (c <- coll) {
      f(c, i)
      i += 1
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
Vector(9, 11, 34).foreachWithIndex { (el, i) =>
  println(el, i)
}
```

Raises the following error:

```
error: value foreachWithIndex is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
Vector(9, 11, 34).foreachWithIndex { (el, i) =>
```

However the code works when I explicitly apply the conversion method:

```
iforeach[Int, Vector[Int]](Vector(9, 11, 34)).foreachWithIndex { (el, i) =>
  println(el, i)
}
```

Output:

```
(9,0)
(11,1)
(34,2)
```

How do I make it make it work without explicit application of a conversion method? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to extend Iterable:

```
class RichIter[A, C](coll: C)(implicit i2ri: C => Iterable[A]) {
    def foreachWithIndex[B](f: (A, Int) => B): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    for (c <- coll) {
      f(c, i)
      i += 1
    }
  }
}

implicit def iter2RichIter[A, C[A]](ca: C[A])(
    implicit i2ri: C[A] => Iterable[A]
): RichIter[A, C[A]] = new RichIter[A, C[A]](ca)(i2ri)

Vector(9, 11, 34) foreachWithIndex {
  (el, i) => println(el, i)
}
```

output:

```
(9,0)
(11,1)
(34,2)
```

See [this post by Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-pimp-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you have to parameterize `CC` if you do it that way or the type inferencer can't figure out what `A` is.  The other short answer is do it the way I describe in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846).

To expand a little bit more, there's really no reason that you need `CC <: TraversableLike`--just have it take a `Traversable` and start with `iforeach[A](coll: Traversable[A])`!  You don't need to use fancy type bounds in order to use a superclass/supertrait.  If you want to do something more complicated where you return another collection with collection type preserved, then you need to use builders and such, which I describe in the other question.

Comment: Actually it's just one method from the set of extra methods I am trying to implement. Some of those other methods need constructing a  new collection of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're interested in is only iterating with an index, you might as well just skip the whole pimping part and do something like

```
coll.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (elem, index) =>
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: How about `mapWithIndex` then? The list goes on.