# How can I add cross product based methods to scala collections?

Tags: scala, collections, enrich-my-library

hopefully this will be a simple question about library pimping (because other questions on that subject tend to generate answers beyond my current skill level).

All I want to do is map over the cross product of a collection with itself.

```
val distances = points.crossMap(_ distance _)  // points: List[Point3d]
```

So I attempted to pimp `Traversable` thus:

```
implicit def toSelfCrossMappable[A](xs: Traversable[A]) = new {
  def crossMap[B](f: (A, A) => B) = xs.flatMap(a => xs.map(f(a, _)))
}
```

But it doesn't work (it's not doing the implicit conversion) and I don't understand why not (I'm pretty new to scala).  I also tried the method suggested in [Enriching Scala collections with a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823213/pimping-a-method-on-scala-collections) which left me with:

```
implicit def toSelfCrossMappable[A, C[A]](xs: C[A])(implicit c: C[A] => Traversable[A]) = new SelfCrossable[A, C[A]](xs)(c)

class SelfCrossable[A, C](xs: C)(implicit c: C => Traversable[A]) {
  def crossMap[B](f: (A, A) => B) = xs.flatMap(a => xs.map(f(a, _)))
}
```

, but that throws the same error as my (simpler looking) way.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `for(a <- points; b <- points) yield (a distance b)` or `points.flatMap{ a => points.map{ b => a distance b } }`

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should clarify, when I said "all I want to do is" what I really meant was "the core of the problem I'm having can be reduced to".  There's more to the real problem that motivates me wanting to use implicit conversions.

Comment: You should please present your error messages.

Comment: ok, might not be a solution to your problem as you say there is more to it. But there is a `combination` function in `SeqLike` traversables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this can be done with `IsTraversableLike`,

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

import scala.collection.generic.{ CanBuildFrom, IsTraversableLike }
import scala.collection.GenTraversableLike

class SelfCrossMappable[A, Repr](xs: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  def crossMap[B, That](f: (A, A) => B)
    (implicit
      cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That],
      itl: IsTraversableLike[That] { type A = B }
    ) = xs.flatMap { a => itl.conversion(xs.map(f(a, _)))
  } 
}

implicit def toSelfCrossMappable[Repr](xs: Repr)
  (implicit traversable: IsTraversableLike[Repr]) =
    new SelfCrossMappable(traversable.conversion(xs))
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> List("foo", "foo", "bar").crossMap(_ == _)
res0: List[Boolean] = List(true, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, true)
```

Comment: Is there a version that will work with 2.9?  Also, if I were to ask why that works (and why mine didn't) would the answer fry my brain?

Comment: you might want to check the [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_0.html) to understand what's going on with the `CanBuildFrom`. I don't think that you need so much knwoledge of advanced scala to get it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend upgrading to 2.10, but if you can't, `IsTraversableLike` will compile under 2.9.x so you could copy its source from the Scala distribution into your project.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.10 you can use implicit classes directly (Miles' answer uses the `IsTraversableLike` helper which also requires Scala 2.10). It seems that the `toSelfCrossMappable` (horrible name BTW) is not needed for standard collections. The following works for me:

```
import collection.generic.{CanBuildFrom, IsTraversableLike}
import collection.GenTraversableLike

implicit class CanCrossMap[A, Repr](xs: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  def crossMap[B, That](f: (A, A) => B)(
    implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That], 
             itl: IsTraversableLike[That] { type A = B }): That = 
      xs.flatMap { a => itl.conversion(xs.map(f(a, _)))
  } 
}
```

Another option is to leave out `IsTraversableLike` completely:

```
import collection.GenTraversableOnce

implicit class CanCrossMap[A, Repr](xs: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  def crossMap[B, That <: GenTraversableOnce[B]](f: (A, A) => B)(
    implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = 
      xs.flatMap { a => xs.map(f(a, _))}
}
```

Example:

```
Vector((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)).crossMap { case ((ax, ay), (bx, by)) =>
  val dx = bx - ax
  val dy = by - ay
  math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
}
```

Miles answer covers a few extra cases, where the collection is not directly a `GenTraversableLike`, namely `Array` and `String` (try substituting `Vector` for `Array` in the last example).