# Scala: Compiler can't find FromRepr, HasElem or implicitConversions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm attempting to pimp TraversableLike using Miles Sabins answer to [How do I apply the enrich-my-library pattern to Scala collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-pimp-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections) However the compiler doesn't recognise FromRepr, HasElem or implicitConversions

```
package packMain
import scala.collection.generic.{ CanBuildFrom, FromRepr, HasElem }
import language.implicitConversions

class ImplClasses {}

FromRepr is not a member of scala.collection.generic
HasElem is not a member of scala.collection.generic
not found object language
```

I've tried using Eclipse Indigo with Scala plug-in 2.02 and 2.9.2 Final and Eclipse 4.2 Juno with Scala plug-in 2.1M2 and 2.10.0M7
Edit:

```
import language.implicitConversions._ //works in 2.10M7 as gilad hock's comment
import scala.collection.generic.FromRepr._ //object FromRep is not a member of ...
import scala.collection.generic.HasElem._ //object HasElem is not a member of ...
```

Comment: The 2.9.2 one certainly isn't going to work because that was before the change.

Comment: to get the implicitis to work, you need to import them explicitly, and not just the containing package. you can use a wildcard: `import language.implicitConversions._`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the implicitis to work, you need to import them explicitly, and not just the containing package. you can use a wildcard: `import language.implicitConversions`**`._`**

**EDIT:**
as for `FromRepr` & `HasElem`, i can't find those in the [package](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/package.html). also, after reading *Miles Sabin* answer on [How do I apply the pimp-my-library pattern to Scala collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-pimp-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections), i noticed he said: *As of [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/73f7001d963a80950751b4e13b95b05d2526edc8) it's a lot easier to...* which tells me it's not an integral part of the scala library (yet?), or else, he probably would link to the package definition, and not to a certain commit on github. so you can clone, and build yourself from the source.

Comment: Yes thanks, that works for the implicitConversions but not for FromRepr or HasElem