# Adding a pairwise difference to generic collections - implicit resolution doesn't kick in

Tags: scala, collections, implicit-conversion

Ok, so I have this:

```
implicit final class RichIterableLike[A, Repr <: IterableLike[A, Repr]](val it: Repr) 
  extends AnyVal {
  def pairDiff[To](implicit num: Numeric[A], cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, To]): To = {
    val b     = cbf(it)
    val iter  = it.iterator
    if (iter.hasNext) {
      var pred = iter.next()
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        import num.mkNumericOps
        val succ = iter.next()
        b += succ - pred
        pred = succ
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
}
```

This compiles, but doesn't kick in:

```
val stabs = IndexedSeq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
stabs.pairDiff
```

Gives: `value pairDiff is not a member of IndexedSeq[Double]`

Explicit conversion works:

```
new RichIterableLike[Double, IndexedSeq[Double]](stabs).pairDiff
```

... how to fix this?

---

**EDIT**

If I apply the approach [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-enrich-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections#5411133), it works:

```
implicit final class RichIterableLike[A, CC[~] <: Iterable[~]](val it: CC[A]) 
  extends AnyVal {
  def pairDiff[To](implicit num: Numeric[A], cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, To]): To = {
  ...
}
```

But the question remains, what is the crucial difference that makes the implicit lookup kick in in the latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the implicit lookup to work it needs a link between `A` and `Repr` (`IterableLike` demands that link). You pass it in as an argument, so that argument should be typed as `Repr[A]`. That means you need to modify your signature so it will look something like this:

```
RichIterableLike[A, Repr[X] <: IterableLike[X, Repr[X]]](val it: Repr[A])
```

With the above signature you say:

> I have an object that accepts a type parameter, I will name that object `Repr` and when you pass it in I would like to capture the type parameter as well. I will name that type parameter `A`. As an extra condition I want the type of `Repr` to conform to the signature of `IterableLike`

Comment: "`IterableLike` demands that link"—why? and how? Its signature is `trait IterableLike[+A, +Repr]` with no constraints on `Repr`, and in particular not requiring `Repr` to have a type parameter on its own.

Comment: You are right, I went back to the documentation and couldn't find it. In the source it is documented: `@tparam Repr the type of the actual collection containing the elements`. All implementations of `IterableLike` use it like this: `Seq[A] extends IterableLike[A, Seq[A]]` (usually via a another trait, `SeqLike` in this case).