# Guidelines for writing Scala API as wrapper over Java API

Tags: java, scala

I have java product with rich set of api. I want to write scala api as a wrapper over those java api. Are there any guidelines for the same. Please share your experience

Comment: You might want to look at Pimp/enrich my library approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-enrich-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections

Comment: You haven't accepted answers to your previously asked questions....

Comment: This question is way too vague. There are as many reasons for writing a Scala wrapper for a Java library as there are for writing a library in Scala. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps if you offered some API samples to give an idea of the kind of thing you want to wrap?  Feel free to change names to protect the innocent...

Comment: Considering Scala runs in the JVM, why is an extra API needed?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very vague question as others have noted, but I suppose there are some broad suggestions:

- Use [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters%24) to translate Java collections to Scala collections.
- Use Scala annotations to represent properties or characteristics represented by other means in Java. Examples of these include `@deprecated`, `@throws`, and `@BeanProperty`. `@BeanProperty` is especially useful if you want to use a library that specifically demands JavaBeans (*i.e* conforms to the specification).
- If the Java code uses Spring, maybe look into [Spring Scala](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala) if necessary. Or use more `constructor-arg`s. Or `asInstanceOf` to cast any beans you manually fetch from the context.
- Build files. Perhaps you want to replace any Java-specific build mechanism with SBT. Or transform your Java-focused Gradle build file to be more Scala-focused. That kind of thing.

That's all I can think of. Hopefully others will point out other considerations I've missed.