# How do I apply the enrich-my-library pattern to Scala collections? For scala 2.11+

Tags: scala

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-enrich-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections) with excellent answers on this topic

Enhancing collections is a rather common use case and some of these answers are no longer valid. Miles Sabin's answer has the prettiest syntax but `HasElem` and `HasRepr` are no longer available in the language. Other answers suggest using View bounds, which are deprecated.

What is the "proper way" to enhance collections nowadays (2.11+)?

Is there a way to avoid using the unusual builder syntax and use normal collection methods instead (as in Mile's answer)?