# Work with collection keeping the type information

Tags: scala, generics, collections, scala-collections

I have a following extension to `Traversable`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object ContainerHelpers {

  implicit class TraversableOps[X](a: Traversable[X]) {
    def partitionByType[T <: X: ClassTag]: (Traversable[T], Traversable[X]) = {
      val (typed, other) = a.partition {
        case _: T => true
        case _ => false
      }
      (typed.map(_.asInstanceOf[T]), other)
    }

  }

  // test case:
  trait T
  case class A(i: Int) extends T

  val s = Seq[T](A(0), A(1))
  val sa = s.partitionByType[A]
  sa // I would like this to be Seq[A], not Traversable[A]

}
```

The extension works fine, however it does not keep a collection type - it always returns `Traversable`. I would like to write it so that `partitionByType` would use the type information known by `partition` and `map`, therefore type of `sa` should be `(Seq[A], Seq[T])`, not `(Traversable[A], Traversable[T])`. How can I do this, perhaps using higher-kinded types, or something like that?

Comment: `sa` is of type `(Traversable[A], Traversable[T]) ` not ` Traversable[A]`. Did you mean "I would like `sa` to be of type `(Seq[A], Seq[T])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply the enrich-my-library pattern to Scala collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-enrich-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CanBuildFrom` and build the collections yourself, instead of relying on `TraversableLike`'s implementation and then cast things down. This 
 has the advantage of not doing any casting anywhere, and it does not cost you anything more than the alternative, because the `partition` method in `TraversableLike` does the same.

This is a first stab at getting what you want *(I changed the parametrized types' names for clarity)*:

```
implicit class TraversableOps[Elem, T[_Ignore] <: Traversable[_Ignore]](a: T[Elem]) {
  def partitionByType[Target <: Elem: ClassTag]
     (implicit cbf1: CanBuildFrom[T[Elem], Elem, T[Elem]],
       cbf2: CanBuildFrom[T[Target], Target, T[Target]]) : (T[Target], T[Elem]) = {

    val l = cbf2()
    val r = cbf1()

    for (x <- a) x match{
      case t: Target => l += t
      case _ => r += x
    }

    (l.result, r.result)
 }
}
```

And it works with the following test case:

```
// test case:
trait A
trait B extends A
case class T(i: Int) extends A
case class U(i: Int) extends B

val s1 : List[A] = List(T(0), U(1))
val s2 : Seq[A] = List(T(0), U(1))

val sa1 = s1.partitionByType[T]  //sa1 : (List[T], List[A]) = (List(T(0)),List(U(1)))
val sa2 = s2.partitionByType[T]   //sa2 : (Seq[T], Seq[A]) = (List(T(0)),List(U(1)))
```

Comment: This is nice, no casts, however it basically reimplements `partition`. I would prefer a generic pattern which would allow me extending any collection methods this way, be it `partition`, `map`, `filter` ... Perhaps I want too much, given how complicated collection implementation is.

Answer (score 2):

Use **F-bounded container** to do this, like:

```
  //F[_] extend from Traversable for own the original type of colleciton
  implicit class TraversableOps[X, F[_] <: Traversable[_]](a: F[X]) {
    def partitionByType[T <: X : ClassTag]: (F[T], F[X]) = {
      //cast to Traversable for known partition type 
      val (typed, other) = a.asInstanceOf[Traversable[X]].partition {
        case _: T => true
        case _ => false
      }
      //cast to the target type, Since the original is F-bounded, so when cast also is cast type safe
      (typed.asInstanceOf[F[T]], other.asInstanceOf[F[X]])
    }

  }

  // test case:
  trait T

  case class A(i: Int) extends T

  case class B(i: Double) extends T

  val s = Seq[T](A(0), A(1), B(2.0f))
  val sa: (Seq[A], Seq[T]) = s.partitionByType[A]
  println(sa._1)
  println(sa._2)
```

Comment: I have to admit I do not like those casts. It seems `partition` keeps the type information around (in the `Repr` type) - I would prefer keeping this information instead of casting with assumption we know it.